# How to find the number of possible $4$-colourings for this graph

Tags: graph-theory

I've been struggling to figure out a solution to find the possible configurations of a 4-colouring graph other than simply drawing out all the solutions, can someone please help me to understand a simpler solution. I've attached an image of the graph I've been given

[image: network graph].

Comment: Hint: Notice that B, E, G and H are all adjacent to each other, and so they must have distinct colours. It doesn't matter which colours you individually assign to them, so just pick some colouring. Can you finish the problem from here?

Comment: Another question on this graph by this user: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592703/why-it-is-not-possible-to-find-a-3-colouring-of-this-network-explain-using-pige