# Why it is not possible to find a 3-colouring of this network, explain using pigeon hole principle.

Tags: graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle, network

I can explain why this network must have 4 colours at least but I am struggling to explain it using the pigeon hole principle could anyone help with an explanation? [image]

Comment: $BEHG$ is a $K_4$, so of course four colors are needed. Why bring the pigeonhole principle into it.

Comment: Another question on this graph by this poster: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592656/how-to-find-the-number-of-possible-4-colourings-for-this-graph